# Freeform Pro Plugin Unsupported operand after plugin installation

Tags: solspace, php

we are using freeform pro 4.1.3 and are seeing

form erorr -  [Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /data/websitesmywebsitedir/html/systemtudor/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/acc.freeform.php on line 122] 
on the freeform pro tab in the admin.php page in expressionengine 2.7.3

the line in the file is ;

$field_ids += $form['field_ids'];

Do you know if their is a compatibility or a bug here that we can patch,
the freeform plugin seems to be working OK..do you know if this error can be ignored?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285271/fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types-in

we meet all the server requirements,
ExpressionEngine 2.4+ [2.7.3]
PHP 5.2+ [5.3.3]
MySQL 5+ [5.1.6]
All modern browsers or IE 8+

Thankyou

Update
This is not working on php version 5.3.3 which the shared host is utilising howver it is working on a a dev server php version 5.4.20
I thought this was a pretty simply assignment operation that should work across both these version, i tried changing  to $field_ids = $field_ids + $form['field_ids']; same error.

halp?

Comment: First time I hear of this kind of error. Did you try reuploading the Freeform files and folders? Please make sure the transfer completes. You might want to contact Solspace support with CP/FTP credentials if you need us to have a closer look. :)

Comment: Thanks Solspace for the offer to help and guidance, i had tried to reinstall previously the wrong way via removing from thirdparty file, reuploading and check for updates,which did not do the trick, uninstalling this via control panel,reuploading and reinstalling resolved this issue..so it looks like something went awry with the initial upload,install. is working now!

Comment: Glad to hear things are working now. Feel free to create an answer for this question and mark it as resolved. :)